# LHS:RHS vs functional in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Why does the functional ':=' not aggregate unique rows using 'by' yet LHS:RHS does aggregate using 'by'? Below is a .csv file of 20 rows of data with 58 variables. A simple copy, paste, delim = .csv works. I am still trying to find the best way to post sample data to SO.  The 2 variants of my code are:

```
prodMatrix <- so.sample[, ':=' (Count = .N), by = eval(names(so.sample)[2:28])]
```

---this version does not aggregate the rowID using by---

```
prodMatrix <- so.sample[, (Count = .N), by = eval(names(so.sample)[2:28])]
```

---this version does aggregate the rowID using by---

```
"CID","NetIncome_length_Auto Advantage","NetIncome_length_Certificates","NetIncome_length_Comm. Share Draft","NetIncome_length_Escrow Shares","NetIncome_length_HE Fixed","NetIncome_length_HE Variable","NetIncome_length_Holiday Club","NetIncome_length_IRA Certificates","NetIncome_length_IRA Shares","NetIncome_length_Indirect Balloon","NetIncome_length_Indirect New","NetIncome_length_Indirect RV","NetIncome_length_Indirect Used","NetIncome_length_Loanline/CR","NetIncome_length_New Auto","NetIncome_length_Non-Owner","NetIncome_length_Personal","NetIncome_length_Preferred Plus Shares","NetIncome_length_Preferred Shares","NetIncome_length_RV","NetIncome_length_Regular Shares","NetIncome_length_S/L Fixed","NetIncome_length_S/L Variable","NetIncome_length_SBA","NetIncome_length_Share Draft","NetIncome_length_Share/CD Secured","NetIncome_length_Used Auto","NetIncome_sum_Auto Advantage","NetIncome_sum_Certificates","NetIncome_sum_Comm. Share Draft","NetIncome_sum_Escrow Shares","NetIncome_sum_HE Fixed","NetIncome_sum_HE Variable","NetIncome_sum_Holiday Club","NetIncome_sum_IRA Certificates","NetIncome_sum_IRA Shares","NetIncome_sum_Indirect Balloon","NetIncome_sum_Indirect New","NetIncome_sum_Indirect RV","NetIncome_sum_Indirect Used","NetIncome_sum_Loanline/CR","NetIncome_sum_New Auto","NetIncome_sum_Non-Owner","NetIncome_sum_Personal","NetIncome_sum_Preferred Plus Shares","NetIncome_sum_Preferred Shares","NetIncome_sum_RV","NetIncome_sum_Regular Shares","NetIncome_sum_S/L Fixed","NetIncome_sum_S/L Variable","NetIncome_sum_SBA","NetIncome_sum_Share Draft","NetIncome_sum_Share/CD Secured","NetIncome_sum_Used Auto","totNI","Count","totalNI"
93,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,-123.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,212.97,0,0,0,-71.36,0,0,0,49.01,0,0,67.42,6,404.52
114,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,14.54,0,0,0,0,0,-285.44,0,0,0,49.01,0,0,-221.89,90,-19970.1
1112,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,60.23,0,0,0,0,-101.55,0,-71.36,0,0,0,98.02,0,0,-14.66,28,-410.48
5366,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-71.36,0,0,0,49.01,0,0,-22.35,77631,-1735052.85
6078,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-17.44,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,14.54,0,0,0,0,0,-499.52,0,0,0,49.01,0,0,-453.41,3,-1360.23
11684,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-71.36,0,0,0,49.01,0,0,-22.35,77631,-1735052.85
47358,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-14.43,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-71.36,0,0,0,0,0,0,-85.79,3194,-274013.26
193761,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-101.55,0,-71.36,0,0,0,49.01,0,0,-123.9,9973,-1235654.7
232530,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-71.36,0,0,0,49.01,0,0,-22.35,77631,-1735052.85
604897,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-71.36,0,0,0,49.01,0,0,-22.35,77631,-1735052.85
1021309,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-71.36,0,0,0,0,0,0,-71.36,43262,-3087176.32
1023633,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-71.36,0,0,0,0,0,0,-71.36,43262,-3087176.32
1029726,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,60.23,0,0,0,0,0,0,-71.36,0,0,0,49.01,0,0,37.88,8688,329101.44
1040005,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-71.36,0,0,0,49.01,0,0,-22.35,77631,-1735052.85
1040092,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-71.36,0,0,0,49.01,0,0,-22.35,77631,-1735052.85
1064453,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,14.54,0,212.97,0,0,0,-142.72,0,0,0,0,0,0,84.79,49,4154.71
1067508,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-123.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-71.36,0,0,0,0,0,0,-194.56,4162,-809758.72
1080303,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-71.36,0,0,0,0,0,0,-71.36,43262,-3087176.32
1181005,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-101.55,0,-142.72,0,0,0,98.02,0,0,-146.25,614,-89797.5
1200484,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-101.55,0,-285.44,0,0,0,0,0,0,-386.99,50,-19349.5
```

Comment: Why the quotes around ':='?.

Comment: The back ticks are required when using the functional form of :=.  SO has reserved back ticks so I tried to substitute them.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Are you asking why `:=` behaves as documented?

Comment: About backticks, see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82718/how-do-i-escape-a-backtick-in-markdown

Comment: The functional form for := should produce the same results as the LHS:RHS form. However, in this case they do not and I wanted to know why.

Comment: I still don't understand. Your second example doesn't call `:=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `:=` is making operations *by reference*. It means it will not invoke in-memory copy of your dataset but it will update it in-place.
Making aggregation of your dataset is a copy of it's original unaggregated form.
You can read more about it in [Reference semantics](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html) vignette.

This is a design concept in data.table that `:=` is used to *update by reference* and other forms - `.()`, `list()` or direct expression are used to query data. And query data isn't a *by reference* operation. The *by reference* operation is not able to aggregate rows, it can just calculate aggregates and put it into dataset in-place. Query is able to aggregate dataset because query result is not the same object in memory as original data.table.

Comment: @ jangorecki So neither for of := operation should make a copy or aggregate. I've read the vignette several times over. The LHS:RHS and the functional form should operate the same, correct. Only difference is the functional form allows you to make some comments and might be easier to follow is my understanding.

Comment: @user3067851 added clarification which may helps